# Delete Unnecessary Fields In Standalone Table Using Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, fields-attributes

My question is similar to that I asked [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/204684/delete-empty-and-null-fields-using-arcpy). The script below, however, is intended to delete unnecessary fields from a single standalone table rather than a database full of tables. The answer in the question referenced above has not performed consistently and I am thinking narrowing it down to a single table may provide some insight to why this is so.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

table_name = (r'C:\MyDatabase.gdb\StandAloneTable')
field_names = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(table_name) if not f.required]
keep = True

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table_name, field_names) as cursor:  
    for row in cursor:
        v = row[0]
        if v is None or isinstance(v, basestring) and \
           (v == '<Null>' or \
            v == 0 or \
            v == '' or \
            v == ' ' or \
            v == '  '):
            keep = False
            break

    if keep is False:
        arcpy.DeleteField_management(table_name, field_names)
```

This script runs without error aside from failing to delete the fields populated only with the values identified in first if-statement as I had intended. No fields are being deleted. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Also, while I am testing this script on standalone tables within a file GDB, the standalone tables I plan to eventually run this script for are housed within an ArcSDE geodatabase.

Answer (score 2):

I think the reason nothing is being deleted may be because you `break` the `with` and you're not even hitting your `if keep is False:`

You may want to outdent (un-indent) your `if` block.

**Note:** That said, I believe that if you change this `if` you will delete ALL fields in your `field_names` as you are not restricting to a single field or a specific list of fields to delete.  `arcpy.DeleteField_management(table_name, field_names)` will delete *all* fields in `field_names` and this list hasn't been updated.

The answer in your linked question loops through the fields, and restricts the deletion to just the current field.

```
for field in field_names:
```

---

Doing a quick edit on your linked answer, this should work (although I'm not a fan of setting `keep = False` first as this runs the risk of deleting a field if something weird happens and the `if` block doesn't find a valid value):

```
import os
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\MyDatabase.gdb'
table_name = (r'StandAloneTable')
field_names = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(table_name) if not f.required]

# Iterate over the fields
for field in field_names:
    # Set a test variable to False
    keep = False
    # Iterate over each feature; if it has a non-null value, then set
    #   the test variable to True and then break out of the cursor
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(table_name, field) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            v = row[0]
            if v is not None or \
              (isinstance(v, basestring) \
              and (v.lower.strip() != ''\
                or v != '<null>')):
                keep = True
                break

    # If the test variable was unchanged, delete the field
    if keep is False:
        arcpy.DeleteField_management(fc, field)
```

Comment: I bet that's it. I'd probably set keep to true again too or it will continue to be false and just delete everything after the first time it gets set to false?

Comment: @jbchurchill yes (after re-reading your comment) I agree, `keep` needs to be re-set to `True` for each loop

Comment: @jbch @Mid  I have tried combinations of these recommendations (outdenting `if` block, removing `break`, workspace of a single table), and while sometimes I get deleted fields, the expected fields are not being deleted. With the above script, if all cells in field have, for example `<Null>`, except one, shouldn't `keep = True`? And shouldn't `v != 0` result in `keep = false`?

Comment: @reevesii that is correct, that is what the `if` statement above says - if one of the cells is not `NULL` then `keep = True`.  `v is not None` means if a value is found that isn't `NULL`, i.e. it contains a value.